# Have left view width be dictated by right view width

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I am trying to create a layout where I have an ImageView on the left and a TextView on the right and I want the width of the ImageView to be dictated the amount of text in the TextView up until the minWidth (300dp in this case) of the imageview and if there isnt a lot of text the imageview size would be bigger since the textview width is smaller.

This is what I have

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/image"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textview"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_min="300dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
        android:textSize="48sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I thought this would have worked but the textview seems to overlap the imageview and pushes the imageview off screen.

Is there some way I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a chain with the two views by constraining the start of the *TextView* to the end of the *ImageView*. For the *TextView* specify

```
 app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
```

to keep it within the boundaries of the *ConstraintLayout*. Also, get rid of the *match_parents* for the *ImageView's* height. Use `0dp` (match_constraints) instead.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textview"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_min="300dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
        android:textSize="48sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Still when there is a lot of text the image width is smaller than the 300dp (its can not show at all if the text fills the screen) for the minimum I have set and. I thought minWidth meant that the width of the view would be no smaller than the given size but it looks like I was wrong in that assumption

Comment: @tyczj Have you tried the XML I posted? It doesn't have these issues.

Comment: Oh I copied it wrong, you are right it does seem to work, thank you!